# How can this simple division result in exponentiation?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I have been experimenting with many weird division properties and this is by far the weirdest thing I have found. This is only division and I can't understand how exponentiation could possibly occur here. It's very strange.

Here is the python demo: https://repl.it/@Hexcede/Repeating-Weirdness
I recommend running it so you can see what I'm talking about.

Here is the formula:
$$f(p) = B^D / (B^{D + 1} - p)$$
$B = Base$ (E.g. 10)

$D = Digits$ (Number of digits of space per power)

$p = Power$ (E.g. 2)

It behaves like this:
If p is 2 the infinite sum will contain powers of 2.
If p is 3 the infinite sum will contain powers of 3.
If p is 1/2 the infinite sum will contain **powers of 5** because 1/2 = 0.5.
If p is 1/4 the infinite sum will contain **powers of 25** because 1/4 = 0.25.
Etc, etc.

Notice that this still follows multiplicative rules. It yields powers of 5 for 0.5 because 0.5 = 5/10.

My question is how, and why does this division result in exponential numbers popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rearrange your formula somewhat:

$$f(p)  = \frac{1}{B} \left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{p}{B^{D+1}}}\right).$$

Now we can expand the second term using the geometric series formula
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$$
to get
$$f(p)  = \frac{1}{B} \left(1 + \frac{p}{B^{D+1}} + \left[\frac{p}{B^{D+1}}\right]^2 + \left[\frac{p}{B^{D+1}}\right]^3\cdots\right)$$
which will look like the powers of $p$, spaced out in blocks of $D+1$ digits (with the initial $1/B$ shifting the first term $1$ to be $0.1$, etc).

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing that that formula exists and it definitely explains a lot. And it's pretty simple too!